# Не переводятся значения из модели

Tags: java, android

Есть метод, который апдейтит мои элементы.
Но, к сожалению не все.

К примеру, если я задаю:

```
 setup(getString(R.string.data), false);
```

То позже в зависимости от настроек языка у меня меняется надпись(перевод осуществляется, так как есть в строковых ресурсах все значения).

Теперь собственно вопрос, если мы используем:

```
setup(mak.categoryName, false);
```

где categoryName это `public String categoryName = "";` в нашей модели и вне зависимости от настроек языка, язык categoryName всегда один и тот же.
В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: Я правильно понимаю что вы хотите что бы происходил автоматический перевод ваших строк, которые созданы динамически?

Comment: Перевод работает только для строк, созданных как ресурсы и только для тех из них, для которых созданы локализированные копии в папках с соответствующими квалификаторами. Каким образом вы расчитываете, чтобы сама перевелась динамически созданная строка?